# Kubuntu: Konsole wrap on resize option?

Tags: bash, kubuntu, kde, konsole

Is there any option to enable word wrap in Konsole when the user is resizing the window?

[image]
[image]

If I'm typing commands on my own the word warp applies but only on the commands part.

```
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\u\[\033[00m\]@\[\033[01;35m\]\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;36m\]\w\[\033[01;30m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$(parse_git_branch)\$ '
fi

unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

Comment: You might want to check here:  https://superuser.com/questions/112071/does-any-linux-x-terminal-update-line-wrapping-on-resize  But so far I have only confirmed with `gnome-terminal` on my system that it will do the wrapping.  `konsole` and `xfce4-terminal` don't do it or at least I cannot find any settings for it.  However, if you have `screen` installed it will do it.